# when i input the url in the browser, can't open the Instant apps

Tags: java, android, android-instant-apps

In Android chrome browser, input the instant app url, and launch the webpage, chrome browser go to the webpage, not open the instant apps. 
i want to open the instant apps when open the "instant app url"  in the chrome browser.

Comment: Please post some of the code you have written so far so that we can help you debug this problem. On Stack Overflow you can't expect peers to do the work for you, try solving the problem and then if you run into any issues we will gladly help you out. This isn't a place for free code writing. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help on writing great questions

Comment: Are you writing an instant app, or is this a public app that you cannot work. If so, probably a question for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/instant-app-links#app_links_overview, you need to click a link to open an Instant App by an App Link.  So, if you click your link in an email in gmail, for example, it should launch your Instant App.  Typing the url in a browser will not launch an Instant App.

Comment: Thank you. I found a solution, use the [firebase dynamic link](https://firebase.google.cn/docs/dynamic-links) can jump to instant app when i typing the url in a browser.